Visual Studio Not Recognizing installed SDK - No IntelliSense, No Code Suggestions, Can't Compile
I'm experiencing an issue in Visual Studio related to SDK recognition. When I create a project, I get an error saying

"The generated project content may be incomplete.
The specified SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" could not be found."

(My Visual Studio is in Spanish, so I relied on ChatGPT to get the error message in English, but I can't guarantee it's the exact literal text) which causes IntelliSense to fail. As a result, Visual Studio doesn't recognize functions (console.writeline, methods like .ToLower) unless I explicitly use using System at the begginning of the code, but even then, library functions (like List<>, .add) still aren't recognized. Additionally, I don't receive code suggestions, and I can't compile the code (this is related to IntelliSense not working)..
When I run dotnet --list-sdks in the console, it doesn't return anything—it's as if I had just pressed enter without typing a command. If I run dotnet --info, it shows that no SDKs are installed under the SDK section.
So what I need to fix is this issue with functions not being recognized. I think it is because the SDK isn't being recognized, so I would focus on fixing that first, but I trust your expertise.
I'm currently pursuing a Data Science career and trying to learn C#. I know it's not Python, but it's what I have available. This issue is critical for me because I really need to install Visual Studio on this computer due to time constraints. I would be immensely grateful if you could help me!!!; you'd be my hero.  I've been troubleshooting this for days with no success.

I installed the following pakages

ASP.net  and web development

.NET desktop development
basically what i've installed in other computers and what all my calssmates did.


Here are some of the steps I've already tried:

Installed SNKs
Reinstalled Visual Studio
Installed IntelliSense localized files
Copied configuration settings from other working environments
Added SDK paths to environment variables
Modified the registry by adding an InstallLocation key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64
Tried installing the SDK with a different user profile to rule out permission issues
Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

It is a work computer, and it is under a firewall, but there is no sign of Microsoft domain blocking, and my user is an administrator. I think (and hope) this isn't the problem, but I wanted to mention it just in case.
I'm running Windows 10 Pro, so no strange industry-long term update version of Windows is involved.
Thank you so much for your time.

Run this command:
dotnet --version

If it returns a version number, it means that you have and SDK installed. If it doesn't you need to install it from the Microsoft official webiste. If you have already installed an SDK and the command I wrote above doesn't return a version, a thing I suppose you might be doing wrong is that you are only downloading the SDK and not installing it. After the SDK has landed in your download directory, you have to actually run it, so the SDK can be installed. It might sound dumb, but it's the only thing I can think of. Hope this helps!

I runed that command, and it didn't return a version. I'm uninstalling dotnet 8.401 rebooting, installing it again but noy placing the installer at the root of the c storage. Nope, nothing, same output

PS C:\Windows\system32> dotnet --version
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:

You intended to execute a .NET application:
The application '--version' does not exist.
You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

PS C:\Windows\system32> dotnet --info
Host:
Version:      8.0.8
Architecture: x86
Commit:       08338fcaa5
RID:          win-x86
.NET SDKs installed:
No SDKs were found.
.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

[dotnet - - info output continues] Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Other architectures found:
x64   [C:\Program Files\dotnet]
registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation]
Environment variables:
Not set
global.json file:
Not found
Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/info
Download .NET:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
